# Usando variável como nome de atributo ao fazer $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço pro jQuery considerar o `NomeCampo` como variável e não campo?

```
var NomeCampo = $(this).attr('name');
var ValorCampo = $(this).val();

$.post(FormAction, {"NomeCampo":ValorCampo},
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está criando o objeto no formato `JSON`, que não suporta variáveis como nome da atributos.

Sugiro criar o objeto e setar o campo usando a variável, dessa forma:

```
var NomeCampo = $(this).attr('name');
var ValorCampo = $(this).val();
var payload = {};

payload[NomeCampo] = ValorCampo;

$.post(FormAction, payload,
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: Nossa cara, muito obrigado, funcionou aqui.

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas não se trata de JSON, e sim da notação literal de objeto.

Comment: @bfavaretto, agora entendi o que você disse, não sabia que existia distinção entre formato JSON e literal (achei que ambos eram JSON), muito boa sua constatação.